# temporary table error due to subquery multiple rows

Tags: mysql

I have a query which works as I need... however, I want to turn it into a temporary table... when I add the line 'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temptable' an error pops up in phpmyadmin saying that the subquery returns more than 1 row. 
Any ideas?

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temptable
SELECT *, 
(SELECT judgement FROM wwlpredictedoveralljudgements p1 WHERE p1.pupilID=x.pupilID && p1.subject=x.subject 
 && p1.dateAchieved=(SELECT MAX(p2.dateAchieved) FROM wwlpredictedoveralljudgements p2 WHERE p1.pupilID=p2.pupilID && p1.subject=p2.subject
                    && p2.dateAchieved>'2018-08-25 00:00:00' && p2.dateAchieved<'2018-12-31 00:00:00')) AS endOfTerm1,
(SELECT judgement FROM wwlpredictedoveralljudgements p4 WHERE p4.pupilID=x.pupilID && p4.subject=x.subject 
 && p4.dateAchieved=(SELECT MAX(p5.dateAchieved) FROM wwlpredictedoveralljudgements p5 WHERE p4.pupilID=p5.pupilID && p4.subject=p5.subject
                    && p5.dateAchieved>'2018-08-25 00:00:00' && p5.dateAchieved<'2019-03-28 00:00:00')) AS endOfTerm2

FROM (
SELECT u.legalFirstName, u.legalSurname, u.form, p3.pupilID, p3.subject
FROM wwlpredictedoveralljudgements p3
LEFT JOIN users u USING(pupilID)
WHERE u.ncYear<7
GROUP BY p3.pupilID, p3.subject
)x
```

Comment: You will get that error even without the create table,

Comment: Which db you are using ????

Comment: @scaisEdge MySQL

Comment: @P.Salmon - my previous thoughts were incorrect. I stand corrected. The query DID work... but ONLY because in phpmyadmin it was set to only show the 1st 25 results... there was a row returning multiple later in the list... 2 entries on exactly the same date... obviously leads to an improvement needed to avoid that happening in the first place. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your subquery return more then a row then you should  or use IN operator or reduce the result usin limit 1 eg:

```
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temptable
    SELECT *
      , ( SELECT judgement 
          FROM wwlpredictedoveralljudgements p1 
          WHERE p1.pupilID=x.pupilID 
          AND p1.subject=x.subject 
          AND p1.dateAchieved IN ( 
            SELECT MAX(p2.dateAchieved) 
            FROM wwlpredictedoveralljudgements p2 
            WHERE p1.pupilID=p2.pupilID 
            AND p1.subject=p2.subject
            AND p2.dateAchieved>'2018-08-25 00:00:00' 
            AND p2.dateAchieved<'2018-12-31 00:00:00')) AS endOfTerm1
      , ( SELECT judgement 
          FROM wwlpredictedoveralljudgements p4 
          WHERE p4.pupilID=x.pupilID 
          AND p4.subject=x.subject 
          AND p4.dateAchieved IN (
            SELECT MAX(p5.dateAchieved) 
            FROM wwlpredictedoveralljudgements p5 
            WHERE p4.pupilID=p5.pupilID 
            AND p4.subject=p5.subject
            AND p5.dateAchieved>'2018-08-25 00:00:00' 
            AND p5.dateAchieved<'2019-03-28 00:00:00')) AS endOfTerm2

    FROM (
      SELECT u.legalFirstName, u.legalSurname, u.form, p3.pupilID, p3.subject
      FROM wwlpredictedoveralljudgements p3
      LEFT JOIN users u USING(pupilID)
      WHERE u.ncYear<7
      GROUP BY p3.pupilID, p3.subject
    ) x
```

or

```
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temptable
    SELECT *
      , ( SELECT judgement 
          FROM wwlpredictedoveralljudgements p1 
          WHERE p1.pupilID=x.pupilID 
          AND p1.subject=x.subject 
          AND p1.dateAchieved = ( 
            SELECT MAX(p2.dateAchieved) 
            FROM wwlpredictedoveralljudgements p2 
            WHERE p1.pupilID=p2.pupilID 
            AND p1.subject=p2.subject
            AND p2.dateAchieved>'2018-08-25 00:00:00' 
            AND p2.dateAchieved<'2018-12-31 00:00:00'
            LIMIT 1 )
            LIMIT 1 ) AS endOfTerm1
      , ( SELECT judgement 
          FROM wwlpredictedoveralljudgements p4 
          WHERE p4.pupilID=x.pupilID 
          AND p4.subject=x.subject 
          AND p4.dateAchieved =  (
            SELECT MAX(p5.dateAchieved) 
            FROM wwlpredictedoveralljudgements p5 
            WHERE p4.pupilID=p5.pupilID 
            AND p4.subject=p5.subject
            AND p5.dateAchieved>'2018-08-25 00:00:00' 
            AND p5.dateAchieved<'2019-03-28 00:00:00'
            LIMIT 1 )
            LIMIT 1 ) AS endOfTerm2

    FROM (
      SELECT u.legalFirstName, u.legalSurname, u.form, p3.pupilID, p3.subject
      FROM wwlpredictedoveralljudgements p3
      LEFT JOIN users u USING(pupilID)
      WHERE u.ncYear<7
      GROUP BY p3.pupilID, p3.subject
    ) x
```

Comment: strangely, although I'd used the limit 1 previously, this did the trick and what I did didn't! Thanks for the time / effort.